# Question about the homology groups of the complex projective space $\mathbb{C}P_n$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, morse-theory

My question is how we can compute the homology groups of the complex projective space $\mathbb{C}P_n$ by the following Corollary5.4 at page 31 in Milnor's book：

**Corollary5.4**
If $c_{\lambda+1}=c_{\lambda-1}=0$,then $R_{\lambda}=c_{\lambda}$ and $R_{\lambda+1}=R_{\lambda-1}=0$.

where $c_{\lambda}$ is the number of the critical points of index $\lambda$ of Morse function on manifold $M$,and $R_{\lambda}$ is the $\lambda$th Betti number of manifold M.

I can not firgure out the details,please give me some help! Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: consider the function $$f\colon [z_0:z_1:\dots:z_n]\mapsto\frac{\sum_{j=0}^n j\lvert z_j\rvert^2}{\sum_{j=0}^n \lvert z_j\rvert^2}$$

Comment: I can not understand what you mean,could you give me more details!

Comment: Show that $f$ has exactly $n+1$ critical points, one for each even index and they are all nondegenerate.  Now use the corollary.